# find the homogeneous linear 8th order differential equation with constant coefficients with two answers given.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

These are two answers of a homogeneous linear $8$th order differential equation with constant coefficients:

$y_1(t)=2e^{-4t}t\cos(2t)$,

$y_2(t)=-t^{2}e^{t}$.

and we know that this equation has an answer that is convergence to a non-zero number in ${t}\to\infty$
how can I find the equation and the general solution?

Comment: @Moo because it's told that the other solution is convergence! and honestly that's where i lost the track and can't figure the problem out.

Comment: @Moo i used the method and I got $c_1 e^t + c_2 e^{-4t} (cos(2t)+isin(2t)) + c_3 e^{-4t} (cos(2t)-isin(2t))$. is this true? how can I use the convergency to find Cs?

Comment: @Moo Note: My Equation is $y^5 + 5 y^4 - y^3 -37y^2 + 52y^2 -20y=0$

Comment: @Moo Can you please write it down for me? :( I have no Idea where I'm making a mistake.